# Resque: Exceptions & stack traces

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, debugging, resque, jrubyonrails

I have a JRuby/Rails application comprising a web server to process HTTP requests, a MySQL database, and a Resque worker to process enqueued jobs. When I'm in development mode and something in the web application throws an exception, I get a nice trace in the browser, showing the exception thrown, the line at which it was thrown, relevant data, and a stack traceback.

However, when exception-throwing code executes in a Resque worker, I get nothing, even if I know that the code has thrown an exception. The only way that I can debug is to throw in print statements and figure out where the last print statement was called before the Resque worker threw the exception and crashed.

Is there a way to get the Resque worker to spit out an exception log and stack traceback into the log file (before it crashes), so that I can see what happened?

EDIT - (Thanks for the idea @Viren) - And I don't want to litter my application code with begin/rescue blocks. I'll put the  begin/rescue code in once somewhere to make sure that the exception traceback gets logged, but I don't know where to put it.

Comment: Why not add a Separate Logger for Resque and Catch the error using `begin rescue` block Hope that help

Comment: I don't want to litter my code with begin/rescue blocks looking for the exception. Is there a central place where I can put it in once and get coverage for the entire?

Comment: as far as i know, you should have a failed job that should also have a valid stack-trace. are you sure this has nothing to do with jruby?

Answer (score 1):

You can set your Resque logger to use the Rails logger. For full stack trace you might want to set it to `DEBUG` level, which prints out lots of information. You put it in `initializers/resque.rb`:

```
Resque.logger = Rails.logger
Resque.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG
```

There also [resque-backtrace](https://github.com/orgsync/resque-backtrace) gem, although it has this drawback that it overwrites the backend in Resque so now no jobs will ever make it to the error queue.